How to fetch data from dynamic url using context in react where the url might be null in the beginning
I am trying to fetch data using context and provider. I have to place my provider in higher tree structure due to which it gets call in the first render. My fetch logic is dynamic that is the url comes from specific portion. Example : i have list of category which i get form a static endpoint A of api. When i click on the specific category i get the list of products under it from dynamic end point suppose B. And if i click on the specific product, i get to the detail page from another dynamic end point C. Each these endpoints are have a provider and context.
Now the problem is since the end points are dynamic and the provider are in higher tree strucutre, the url or endpoints are null due to which my application is only showing the loading component.
how can i deal with it.
in my NewsDetails.jsx
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Description } from "../components/ui/Description";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { NewsDetailsContext } from "../components/context/NewsDetailsContext";

export const InnerNews = () => {
  const { uri } = useParams();
  const { setUri } =useContext(NewsDetailsContext);
  useEffect(()=>{
    setUri(uri);
  },[uri]);
  const { details, images }= useContext(NewsDetailsContext);
  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <div className="container mx-auto text-center">
          <div className="my-12">
            <p className=" md:text-4xl text-xl font-extrabold">
              {details.post_title}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="text-justify md:text-center">
            <Description text={details.post_content} />
          </div>
          <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-8 mt-12">
            {images.map((image) => (
              <div key={image.id}>
                <img
                  src={image.path}
                  alt=""
                  className="h-[300px] w-full object-cover"
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

in my main.jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import NewsProvider from "./components/context/NewsContext.jsx";
import NewsDetailsProvider from "./components/context/NewsDetailsContext.jsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
   <NewsProvider>
       <ArticleProvider >
          <NewsDetailsProvider>
              <React.StrictMode>
                 <App />
              </React.StrictMode>
          </NewsDetailsProvider>
       </ArticleProvider>
   </NewsProvider>
);

The way i want to do in NewsDetailsContextProvider.jsx
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Loader } from '../ui/Loader';
export const NewsDetailsContext = createContext();

const NewsDetailsProvider = ({children}) =>{
  const [newsDetails, setNewsDetailsData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading]=useState(true);
  const [uri,setUri] =useState(null);
  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchNewsDetails(){
      try{
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5173/news/child-detail/${uri}`);
        if(!res.ok){
          throw new Error('Network Error');
        }
        const data = await res.json();
        setNewsDetailsData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      }
      catch(error){
        console.error('Error fetching news details data', error);
      }
    }
    fetchNewsDetails();
  }, [uri]);
  const details = newsDetails && newsDetails.child_details.data;
  const images = newsDetails && newsDetails.child_details.images;
  return (
    <NewsDetailsContext.Provider value={{details, images, setUri}}>
      {loading ? <Loader /> : children}
    </NewsDetailsContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default NewsDetailsProvider;


What is dynamic about the URL? What is the URL? Can you [edit] the post to clarify the problem and narrow the focus where the issue is in the code? See [mcve].

I will edit the post and tried to explain my query.
http://localhost:5173/news/child-detail/test
lets suppose this is url. and in my case 'test' will be dynamic. it gets replace by${uri} in fetch.
in my format my fetch has this url => http://localhost:5173/news/child-detail/${uri}
but in the begining the uri will be null which give me error since i have NewsDetailsProvider in the higher tree which get called in the begining of the application rendering. since i don't have end points with null points, in console.log it shows error "Network error"  which i have written in provider.

If making the fetch request is a problem when the uri value is null (or falsey) then a trivial solution is to conditionally make the fetch request when uri is truthy.
Consider the following Example:
const NewsDetailsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [newsDetails, setNewsDetailsData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [uri, setUri] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create an abort controller to cancel in-flight requests if needed
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;

    async function fetchNewsDetails() {
      // toggle loading true when starting request
      setLoading(true);

      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          `http://localhost:5173/news/child-detail/${uri}`,
          { signal }
        );
        const data = await res.json();

        // Store only what you need into state, e.g. details and images
        const { data: details, images } = data.child_details ?? {};
        setNewsDetailsData({ details, images });
      } catch(error) {
        console.error('Error fetching news details data', error);
      } finally {
        // Clear loading regardless of success or failure
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    // Only fetch details if there is truthy URI value
    if (uri) {
      fetchNewsDetails();
    }

    // Return cleanup function to cancel in-fight fetch requests
    // if component unmounts or rerenders.
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [uri]);

  const { details, images } = newsDetails ?? {};

  return (
    <NewsDetailsContext.Provider value={{ details, images, setUri }}>
      {loading ? <Loader /> : children}
    </NewsDetailsContext.Provider>
  );
};

